# SQL Server join tables with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Suppose I have these tables in SQL Server:

**tbl_Applicants**

```
ID | name | typeid | depid
---+------+--------+-------
1  | Mark |  1     | NULL
2  | Ted  |  2     | 1
```

**tbl_ApplicantType**

```
ID | Type
---+----------
1  | Student
2  | Employee
```

**tbl_Department**

```
ID | department_name
---+----------------
1  | Finance
2  | HR
```

I want to join the table so that I can get the result below

This is my desired result:

```
Name |   type   | department
-----+----------+---------------
Mark | Student  | NULL
Ted  | Employee | HR
```

I have this select statement:

```
select 
    a.name, b.type, c.department_name
from 
    tbl_applicants a, tbl_ApplicantType b, tbl_Department c
where 
    a.depid = c.ID and a.typeid = b.ID
```

This is the result I get right now:

```
Name |   type   | department
-----+----------+------------
Ted  | Employee | HR
```

Any idea how to achieve the result I want where I get the null values included?

Comment: Use proper `JOIN` syntax, it's much easier to change to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Extended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Alway* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

If you want all applicants, then you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select a.name, apt.type, d.department_name
from tbl_applicants a left join
     tbl_ApplicantType apt
     on a.tpeid = apt.id left join
     tbl_Department d
     on a.depid = d.ID ;
```

Also note the use of *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.  That is also a best practice.